# Fuzzy SQL Search

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

Given a table:

```
| Role  | Low  | High |
| A     | AA00 | ZZ*  |
| B     | *    |      |
| C     | AA00 | AZ99 |
```

How would I go about performing a query that selects rows where a value falls within the LOW - HIGH range.

e.g. I would like to select Roles A and B if I am comparing Low and High to 'BB' and role B if I am comparing the range to '22'

AB99 should return A, B, C

Comment: This is representative of actual data? So the `*` is being used as a wildcard? And in `B` where the `High` value is `null` - would that also be considered a wildcard?

Comment: yes, this is pretty close to actual data.  SAP role security data to be exact :)  The * is wildcard but not null.  High not needed since Low already encompasses all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CompVal VarChar(100) = '22';

WITH T AS (
  SELECT Role, Low, High
  FROM (
    SELECT 'A' Role, 'AA00' Low, 'ZZ*' High
    UNION
    SELECT 'B' Role, '*' Low, NULL High
    UNION
    SELECT 'C' Role, 'AA00' Low, 'AZ99' High
  ) U
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE @CompVal BETWEEN Low AND High
  OR (@CompVal >= Low AND NULLIF(High, '*') IS NULL)
  OR (NULLIF(Low, '*') IS NULL AND @CompVal <= High)
;
```

I'm assuming that both your `*` and `NULL` values are used like wildcard values. This produces proper results for each of your example cases.

Note that this also depends on which collation you're using. For most (including the default collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) it will be just fine.

**EDIT**: Looking more closely you may want to replace the `WHERE` clause with this:

```
WHERE @CompVal BETWEEN
      REPLACE(ISNULL(Low, '*'), '*', '0000')
  AND REPLACE(ISNULL(High, '*'), '*', 'ZZZZ')
```

Comment: That's perfect.  * is wildcard so B has no upper limit since * encompasses all